# Access to send email method in Salesforce

Tags: apex, profile, send-email

I have a user who find it unable to automatically send out email when tick a supervisor confirmed checkbox. When another user updated the same record for him. The email got sent out smoothly. I have looked at the trigger code, and it is pretty straight-forward to me:

```
trigger Quality_Score_send_Review_request on Quality_Score__c (after update, after Insert) 
{
//Sends Quality Score review to listed supervisor
for(Quality_Score__c QS : Trigger.new)
   {
   if(QS.Audio_Transcribers_Manager__c != null 
       && QS.Supervisor_Confirmed__c == TRUE 
       && QS.Checked_by_Supervisor__c != TRUE
       && QS.Date_Time_AT_received_results__c == null 
      )
     {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        //... messaging composition code here. 

      Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

}}}
```

I have checked all four fields' field level security: Audio_Transcribers_Manager__c, Supervisor_Confirmed__c, Checked_by_Supervisor__c, Date_Time_AT_received_results__c. The user's profile has access to all of them. I have also try to check whether the user has access to send out email. But I am a little bit stuck here in finding out relevant document. Is there any place I should check?

Comment: Did you try adding try/catch block around Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail }); line so that if anything is going wrong for that user! if anything is missing probably you can get the details inside catch block, give it a try !
Also check this question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162195/why-cant-i-receive-the-email/162196#162196 , this might help you.

Comment: Is there any "addError()" method called during this trigger transaction(to any record)?

Comment: @SaumyaRanjanSatapathy No, it doesn't have any