# Salesforce Email are not received by recipient

Tags: email, salesforce-id, apex-email-service, user-management

I have a Salesforce org. Email address in Org is xxx.xxxx@domain.com and domain is a company name hosted on gmail.

When I try to send email(Using apex or standard "Send email" button from objects) to any of the email address of same domain, salesforce shows that email is sent successfully but email is not recieved to recipients.
If I send email to gmail hosted email address like xxx.xxxx@gmail.com, it works fine. Emails are recived by recipients.

I have also tested the "Test Deliverability" process in salesforce, same happens here.

Then I chnage my email address from xxx.xxxx@domain.com tpo xxx@gmail.com. It is working fine now. All emails are recived by recipients.

How I use the xxx.xxxx@domain.com email address in salesforce org and send email successfully(xxx.xxxx@domain.com is valid email address)?

Is there any setting which I need to check or set?

Comment: Check in Spam folder of your mailbox. The email from Salesforce might be there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162195/why-cant-i-receive-the-email/162196#162196 This might help you.!

Comment: There is no email in Spam. Also I have tried the https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162195/why-cant-i-receive-the-email/162196#162196 setting and test Deliverability process too, but not receive any email.

Comment: Can anybody Please answer this Question? I am also facing same issue in sandbox environment.

Answer (score 2):

This issue can be resolved by checking the checkbox "**Enable compliance with standard email security mechanisms**" in Deliverability setting in setup.